# Virtual destructor needed for class which is both derived and base?

Tags: c++, virtual, destructor

Say we have the following:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    virtual ~A() { std::cout << "destr A\n"; }
};

struct B : A
{
    // no need to be virtual?
    ~B() { std::cout << "destr B\n"; }
};

struct C : B
{
    ~C() { std::cout << "destr C\n"; }
};
```

Now, I create an instance of `C` and assign it to a pointer of its base class `B`.

```
int main()
{
    B* b = new C{};
    delete b;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
destr C
destr B
destr A
```

What surprised me a little is that the object gets destroyed correctly (all three destructors are called). According to the output, I would say `~B()` is a virtual destructor: `~B()` dispatches to `~C()`, then `~B()` finishes and finally, `~A()` is called. Is this statement correct?

I know that, if some function of a base class is virtual, the function in the derived class which overrides the one in the base class is virtual as well. I did not know that was true for destructors as well. Is `~B()` virtual because I declared `~A()` with the `virtual` function specifier?

Comment: Declaring the destructor of any base class of C (either A or B or both) as virtual, should suffice.

Comment: "The destructor" is the same function, but its spelling depends on which class it belongs to.

Comment: You can even use `override`: `~B() override {/*..*/}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is `~B()` virtual because I declared `~A()` with the `virtual` function specifier?

Yes. Per https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.dtor#10:

> If a class has a base class with a virtual destructor, its destructor (whether user- or implicitly-declared) is virtual.